# Safe PIR GPIO input

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, gpio

Would like to connect a sensor (PIR) who's output works at a different voltage level to the micro-controller input. Is the schematic correct and safe enough? (works on breadboard) 
The GPIO pullup is around 35k
PIR works on 5V - output is around 4.6V

My other thoughts were:
Use an opto-isolator - costly

Use potential divider without pullup and diode - concerns on input pin safety[image: My Schematic]

Comment: There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Looks good to me. There seems to be enough voltage in the base to pull down the GPIO with the NPN transistor. How much output impedance does the PIR have? Also, how much current can it supply? I'm asking because I wonder if you will saturate the NPN as a switch and want to make sure you don't burn the PIR with the B-C saturation current

Comment: Thanks for the schematic editor tip. Didn't see that.

Comment: The voltage to the transistor is enough (tested) to pull it to GND, am not sure about the impedance thou - It can light up an led with a 2.2k resistor. I measured the current PIR to transistor an is 3 microamp.

Comment: Check the microcontroller datasheet carefully and see whether it has some 5V-tolerant GPIO pins.  Many 3.3V uCs do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, a simple voltage devider. The downside is that while on the high state, the circuit leeches about 8 micro amps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ2NU1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem I see with your solution is that it will drain the 4.8V signal to the ground, and not allow the 3.3V through, unless you can allow 4.7 mA through the PIR.

I would also consider adding a resistor to the GPIO. as it stands, it looks like you're going to be pulling immense amounts of current straight to the ground.

Comment: I was considering there voltage divider option. PIR is in high state only for trigger periods so the current leech would be acceptable.